# How can I get macOS like window edge to edge alignment in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, desktop-customization

Is there any utilities to get this windows behaviour in Windows 10? [That's I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5njPp.png)

Answer (score -1):

Tiles and Magnet are apps that allow you to snap your windows to a section of your screen by dragging the windows to an edge of your screen or by using hotkeys: 1/2, 1/3, or 1/4 of your screen. I'm not sure if they have the function to snap when you drag edges together but you can essentially do that by snapping them to adjacent sections. I personally use Tiles because it seems to work smoother and animations are less choppy. Also learn the hotkeys and you'll be so much more productive! This needs to be made native function already...